# making Modaless dialog on top

Tags: mfc

I have application in which I will create multiple modalless dialogs, and I want the modaless dialog to be in top without making it top most in setwindowpos(), any alternate way??

I want to do this because , when I click on window the opened modaless dialog should exist as it is but focus will be on window, if I make top most it wil not allow to keep other windows on top

Comment: Not a direct answer but you could make Windows behave like this in general and then it would presumably work for your app.  See   http://superuser.com/questions/76315/how-to-make-mouse-in-windows-7-act-the-same-as-windows-xp

Comment: A modeless dialog will always be on top of its parent window, if that helps. So you can make sure that the parent window is set appropriately when you create it.

Comment: I think you want to make tool bars which don't deactivate the main app. That depends on your application design.

Comment: This is unrelated to MFC. The rules are baked into the Win32 windowing system. See [Window Features: Owned Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows) to solve this.